# Can Background workers share functions

Tags: vb.net

I have a rather complicated window form application that is managing 2 background worker threads.  Everything is running as expected but I find myself writing things twice, once for each background worker and I'm not sure if this is required.  For example, I have in one of the Do_Work routines:

```
Do While ThisQueue.FIleList.Count > 0
  ..Do some work..
  Call Worker1DoSomething(SomeVar)
  ..Do more work..
Loop
```

In the second background worker's Do_Work routine I have:

```
Do While ThisQueue.FileList.Count > 0
  ..Do some work..
  Call Worker2DoSomething(SomeVar)
  ..Do more work..
Loop
```

Can I Have 1 function called by both Do_Work routines and not get things messed up?  Instead of having two functions: Worker1DoSomething(byval thisvar as string) and Worker2DoSometing(byval thisvar as string)  just have 1 function  WorkerFunctionDoSomething(byval thisvar as string)  ?

The biggest reason why I ask is that I have 8 functions that are really 4 functions that are called from either Do_Work routine and it would simplify the code big time.  One of the functions writes data to a SQL server, which was the main reason why I started out going this method.

Thanks in advance for any help or suggestions!
Fred

Comment: Are these two worker threads running at the same time? If so, you need some locking method in place, to avoid concurrent, overlapping, calls to a procedure that might (will) not like it, concurrent use of the same collections/objects/variables etc.

Comment: The `Call` keyword is one of those things that exists for backwards compatibility with older vb6-era code. There's no reason to ever use it in VB.Net and it doesn't actually do anything. Even the examples in the docs are better handled with parentheses.

Comment: Jimi;Yes, both worker threads are running at the same time this is what caused me to write it the way it is now, not wanting any concurrent or overlapping issues.  Joel:  Old habits die hard.  :)  I typed the code out here without thinking.  I still find myself typing it into the editor time to time.  Thanks for the reminder!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You certainly can do that. Like any event handler, inside the `DoWork` event handler, the `sender` parameter is the object that raised the event. If you set up a relationship between each `BackgroundWorker` and the data you want it to use and/or the method(s) you want to execute, you can use the `sender` to get that data and/or method(s) and make use of them. One way to do that is with a `Dictionary` with the `BackgroundWorker` objects as keys:

```vb
Private ReadOnly workMethodsByWorker As New Dictionary(Of BackgroundWorker, Action(Of Object)) From {{BackgroundWorker1, AddressOf Method1},
                                                                                                     {BackgroundWorker2, AddressOf Method2}}

Private data As Object

Private Sub BackgroundWorkers_DoWork(sender As Object, e As DoWorkEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.DoWork,
                                                                                     BackgroundWorker2.DoWork
    Dim worker = DirectCast(sender, BackgroundWorker)
    Dim method = workMethodsByWorker(worker)

    method(data)
End Sub

Private Sub Method1(data As Object)
    '...
End Sub

Private Sub Method2(data As Object)
    '...
End Sub
```

Another option is to define your own class that inherits `BackgroundWorker` and adds a property for the method to be executed and use that class instead of the standard `BackgroundWorker`:

```vb
Imports System.ComponentModel

Public Class BackgroundWorkerEx
    Inherits BackgroundWorker

    Public Property WorkMethod As Action(Of Object)

End Class
```

```vb
Private data As Object

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    BackgroundWorkerEx1.WorkMethod = AddressOf Method1
    BackgroundWorkerEx2.WorkMethod = AddressOf Method2
End Sub

Private Sub BackgroundWorkers_DoWork(sender As Object, e As DoWorkEventArgs)
    Dim worker = DirectCast(sender, BackgroundWorkerEx)
    Dim method = worker.WorkMethod

    method(data)
End Sub

Private Sub Method1(data As Object)
    '...
End Sub

Private Sub Method2(data As Object)
    '...
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Jmcil;  I like your first suggestion; I'm already using a basic class object to pass prams into each of the Do_Worker routines.  I can add the Functions to this class and call it from within the Do_work routine, right?  For example, I have a class called WorkerPrams.vb, with a number of public properties and public functions, which is getting passed into the Do_Work routine as e then retrieved :  Dim Params as WorkerPrams = e.arguement    From here, I could call  Params.Function(value)    About right?  Super Thanks for the direction... I'll post my results shortly!

Comment: Just wanted to indicate this is solved; perfectly!  Awesome idea JMcil!  De-Cluttered the main module.  Thanks to all for posting and the help!